# Python Flask WTForms FloatField allow 1,0 and 1.0 allow comma and dot

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a flask app where a user can submit a room. There is a price field which is a FloatField in my WTForms:

```
preis = FloatField('Preis p.P.', validators=[Optional()])
```

If the input is correct (with a dot) it works fine, example:

```
1.00
```

But if a comma is used it triggers an error, example:

```
1,00
```

[image]

My Idea was to catch this in my main.py, but the problem is that the default error message from WTForms triggers first:

I tried to convert the float to string, check if `,` is in this string and use a simple `replace(",",".")` and then convert back to float.

---

An other side question, how do I change this default `Not a valid float value` message to a custom message?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you change the locale of your machine? Try setting it to spanish locale. Now it may work for the comma (but not for the period)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subclass FloatField and add the `replace` function to its `process_formdata()` function.

```
class MyFloatField(FloatField):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            try:
                self.data = float(valuelist[0].replace(',', '.'))
            except ValueError:
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext('Not a valid float value'))
```

Here you can also change the Error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest use of **DecimalField** instead of **FloatField**

It will let you avoid taking care of dots and commas.

i.e.:

```
preis = DecimalField('Preis p.P.', places=2, validators=[Optional()])
```

I also attach a small hint from https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/fields/#basic-fields

> class wtforms.fields.DecimalField(default field arguments, places=2,
> rounding=None, use_locale=False, number_format=None)[source]

Comment: Your solution did not work for me. The solution from @MrLeeh did.